# React Native Websocket JSON communication

Tags: android, json, react-native, websocket

I'm trying to set up a Websocket client that communicates with a websever via JSON. I don't find any good examples online.

I only found this code online :

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://host.com/path');

ws.onopen = () => {
  // connection opened
  ws.send('something'); // send a message
};

ws.onmessage = (e) => {
  // a message was received
  console.log(e.data);
};

ws.onerror = (e) => {
  // an error occurred
  console.log(e.message);
};

ws.onclose = (e) => {
  // connection closed
  console.log(e.code, e.reason);
};
```

I don't know how to integrate this code into my app-code to function. 
Do I need to install some packages for it?
I'm doing a project for my studies, and at the end I should have a Quiz-App which connects to a server to get the questions and answers for the game.

Thanks for anny help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need anything else to work with a WebSocket in react-native (or any relatively new JS environment [for that matter](http://caniuse.com/#search=websocket)). The example that you found covers pretty much anything that you need to get started. The next step is to bind that to your React logic. For instance, you can create a `WebSocketController` component that would look (details omitted) like this

```
class WebSocketController extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    this.ws = new WebSocket('ws://host.com/path');
    this.ws.onmessage = this.handleMessage.bind(this);
    this.ws.onerror = //...
  }
  handleMessage(e){
    // dispatch event (á la redux, flux), or do something else
  }
  componentWillUnmount(){
    // close WS
  }
}
```

Render this within your React hierarchy and it will be started along the rest of your components. If you need something more specific, let us know.

Comment: I implemented your code, with console.log(e.data) in the method handleMessage(e) , just to see if it works but I get this error:  ERROR  Packager can't listen on port 8081
Most likely another process is already using this port
Run the following command to find out which process:

   lsof -i :8081 

Then, you can either shut down the other process:

   kill -9 <PID> 

or run packager on different port.

Comment: That is a different error, that usually gets fixed by checking the output of lsof. Probably you have another instance of the packager running there.

Comment: Ok , this error is not there anymore, but when I try to run my app with the implemented code with console.log(e.data) it doesn't show me anything on the console. In my IDE Webstorm console it's alternating from this message [intellij] Established a connection with the Proxy (Packager) to the React Native application
to this message
[intellij] Disconnected from the Proxy (Packager) to the React Native application. Retrying reconnection soon...

Comment: Are you sure you were not getting these errors before you implemented your changes?

Comment: Oh yes you're right ! Excuse me this error I had already before!

Comment: dispatching event with redux or flux , is it better to it with one of them?

Comment: As you see fit, depends on what you want to do, but usually for big apps such solutions are recommended.